# Powershell - Specifying variable path for usernames

Tags: powershell, path, accounts

I have tried searching for this, but I do not think I am using the correct words.

I am creating a script that needs to work on many environments. One of the specifications, is that I need to be able to delete a certain directory in a users AppData. Problem with it, is I do not know how to set a dynamic path.

I.e. **C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\X** compared to **C:\Users\User2\AppData\Local\X**

How would I get and specify a series of user accounts on the local machine, ideally with out polling AD?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you show the relevant code where you need to use this?

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't have anything yet, heh. I am thinking on how I will write this out before actually doing it. I have a citrix enviroment. I need to delete files in a series of directories, but each one is in a different users folder. Other than the name of the account in the path, each directory is identical. Almost like the account name is a variable I could pass to the delete line.

Comment: You should try writing something. And looking up how to format/concatenate strings/etc. in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the environment variables for paths to local resources using `Get-ChildItem` like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path env:
```

This will show you all environment variables and their value without the need to query Active Directory, the one you want for AppData\Local is called `LOCALAPPDATA`

To use an environmental variable in a function the syntax is `$ENV:<Name>` so to use the environmental variable for `LOCALAPPDATA` you would use `$ENV:LOCALAPPDATA`

Play around with the environmental variables and start coding your script, if you have additional questions you can then post your script and we can contribute a more specific answer to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

To get user names from AD, AD module must be installed on the system from which you run the queries.

```
#Export to a csv file user names and use it as the source.
Note that this command will export all users from your AD.

    Get-ADuser -filter * | select name | Export-Csv c:\users.csv
    $users = Import-Csv c:\users.csv

    Foreach ($user in $users.name) {

    $path = "c:\users\$user\appdata\local\X"
    if ( $(Try { Test-Path $path.trim()} Catch { $false }) ) {

        Remove-Item $path -Force -Recurse
     }
    Else {

       write-host "Path not found"
     }

    }
```